# Run Python under Apache already running PHP using mod_wsgi

Tags: mod-wsgi

I am running PHP at the server using apache web-server.
My website is running nice.

Now i need to run python on my web-server without affecting PHP in anyway.

I used the following link to configure mod_wsgi in httpd.conf under apche after installing mode_wsgi.

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide

The configuration I updated is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName www.quipmate.com
    ServerAlias quipmate.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@quipmate.com

    DocumentRoot /usr/local/www/documents

    Alias /robots.txt /usr/local/www/documents/robots.txt
    Alias /favicon.ico /usr/local/www/documents/favicon.ico

    Alias /media/ /usr/local/www/documents/media/

    <Directory /usr/local/www/documents>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess quipmate.com processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP}
    WSGIProcessGroup quipmate.com

    WSGIScriptAlias / /usr/local/www/wsgi-scripts/myapp.wsgi

    <Directory /usr/local/www/wsgi-scripts>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

After updating and restarting apache, I got 404 error on my index.php file in my web document root. Also it did not helped me any way with the python script which was outputed directly on the browser. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

WHich is exactly what one would expect as you used WSGIScriptAlias to mount the WSGI application at the root of the web site, thus hiding everything else on the web site.

You may want to use the AddHandler and mod_rewrite solution described in the end of the section:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationGuidelines#The_Apache_Alias_Directive

This will allow PHP files to take precedence and only fall through to the WSGI application if the request is not satisified.

Comment: I am having a similar problem, can I run `.py` files with this solution? @GrahamDumpleton

Comment: I have written an extensive post about using PHP and Python together at http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2014/09/hosting-php-web-applications-in.html You would need to go through that, work out what might match what you need and try it. After trying it if you have an issue, then post a new and quite specific question explaining very clearly what you are trying to do, what you tried in the configuration, and what failed, including error messages and where they appeared.